# Standalone Consumer (SpringJMS) created another Queue on ActiveMQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms

I created a simple standalone consumer, trying to consume 4 messages sitting on the ActiveMQ. But when I started the application, it created another Queue with the same name as shown in the image below:

[image]

My Project Structure looks like this:

[image]

And code inside classes looks like the following:

**class FebMessageConsumer**

```
package com.consumer.messages.febMessageConsumer;

    import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class FebMessageConsumer {

        @JmsListener(destination = "CDD Feb 21 Queue")
        ///@JmsListener
        public void processFebMessage(String message) {

            System.out.println("Message Retrieved is:" +message);


        }

    }
```

**class FebMessageConsumerApplication**

```
package com.consumer.messages.febMessageConsumer;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class FebMessageConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FebMessageConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

1) What's wrong in the above code?

2) Once I get above thing working,I plan on deploying it as a WAR to Apache Tomcat 8.5. Is it like when I deploy the application or start the application as Java Application, it's going to consume all the messages one by one? OR when I start the application, only one message will be consumed at a time and then I'll have to stop the application and then start again to consume next message?

Here's a [Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IkULFZP-YT6u-fYRbrQetQGl1AkT85i-) to the zipped project in case needed for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing queue name includes quotes.

Use `@JmsListener(destination = "\"CDD Feb 21 Queue\"")`.

It will continually receive messages one by one.

Comment: Great. Thanks. That was a silly mistake from my end. So, I think the scenario of continually receiving messages one by one works when I already have some messages sitting on the queue and after that, I start my consumer application. Could you tell me if after consuming all the messages, a new message is added to the queue, is the deployed WAR still going to keep on receiving it's messages? Thanks

Comment: It will keep receiving messages as they arrive until you undeploy it.